# How to get diagonals of nested list that pass through a given point - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d list like this:

```
thelist=[[0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [1,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,1,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,1,0,0,0], # (3,2) is the 1 in this row
         [0,0,0,1,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,1,0]]
```

And I'm trying to get the 2 diagonals of the 2d list that pass through given coordinates. In the list above, if the coordinates were `(3,2)`, then the two lists would be `[1,1,1,1,1]` and `[0,0,1,0,0,0]`.

I've seen solutions where I could get all the diagonals or a specific diagonal, but I have not been able to find a solution online that can get the diagonals that pass through a point. Here's what I've tried:

```
def find_diagonals(thelist,coor):
    twodiag=[[],[]]
    coor1=[coor[0]-min(coor),coor[1]-min(coor)]
    coor2=[coor[0]-min(coor),coor[1]+min(coor)]
    while True:
       try: 
           twodiag[0].append(thelist[coor1[0]][coor1[1]]) 
           coor1[0]+=1
           coor1[1]+=1
       except IndexError:
           break

    while True:
       try: 
           twodiag[1].append(thelist[coor2[0]][coor2[1]]) 
           coor2[0]+=1
           coor2[1]-=1
       except IndexError:
           break
    return twodiag
```

However, it only returns one diagonal correctly. How can either fix this code or solve the problem in another way? If anything is unclear, I'll be happy to answer it in the comments. Thanks!

Comment: Anyway even not in the main diagonal your code works

Comment: Shouldn't your second diagonal be [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0] instead of [0, 1, 0, 0, 0] ? (Accidentally deleted the previous comment sorry.)

Comment: @Eypros `find_diagonals(thelist,[0,0])` outputs `[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]`, which does work (for the first diagonal). The second diagonal is not correct.

Comment: Yeah you are right it is buggy. Anyway you want 2 diagonal at _any_ point for a _sqaure_ list?

Comment: Yes, for any coordinate in the 2d list, I want to get the two diagonals that pass through the coordinate as lists. My current code only works for one of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
width, height = len(thelist[0]), len(thelist)
size = max(width, height)
valid_x, valid_y = range(width), range(height)

pos = (3,2)
x, y = pos

diag1 = [thelist[i][i-x+y] for i in range(size) if i-x+y in valid_y]
diag2 = [thelist[i][x+y-i] for i in range(size) if x+y-i in valid_y]
print (diag1, diag2)
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

solution using `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
thelist=[[0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [1,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,1,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,1,0,0,0], # (3,2) is the 1 in this row
         [0,0,0,1,0,0],
         [0,0,1,0,1,0]]
lst = matrix = np.array(thelist)

i, j = 3, 2 #position of element
major = np.diagonal(lst, offset=(j - i))
print(major)

minor = np.diagonal(np.rot90(lst), offset=-lst.shape[1] + (j + i) + 1)
print(minor)
```

**Output:**

```
[1 1 1 1 1]
[0 0 0 1 0 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this calculating the offsets:

```
def get_diagonals(alist, coordinates):
    # Diagonal 1
    start = coordinates
    while start[0] > 0 and start[1] > 0:
        start = (start[0] - 1, start[1] - 1)

    diag1 = []
    index = start
    while index[0] < len(alist) and index[1] < len(alist[0]):
        diag1.append(alist[index[0]][index[1]])
        index = (index[0] + 1, index[1] + 1)

    # Diagonal 2
    start = coordinates
    while start[0] < len(alist) - 1 and start[1] > 0:
        start = (start[0] + 1, start[1] - 1)

    diag2 = []
    index = start
    while index[0] >= 0 and index[1] < len(alist[0]):
        diag2.append(alist[index[0]][index[1]])
        index = (index[0] - 1, index[1] + 1)

    return diag1, diag2


thelist=[[0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [1,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,1,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,1,0,0,0], # (3,2) is the 1 in this row
         [0,2,0,1,0,0],
         [3,0,0,0,1,0]]

coord = (3,2)

get_diagonals(thelist, coord)
> ([1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0])
```

The code is straight forward and calculates positions within the matrix that are on the diagonal one by one.

edit: fixed off-by-one error

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is easy linear function:

```
def find_diagonals(input_list, coordinates):
    diagonals = [[], []]
    row_coordinate, column_coordinates = coordinates
    for row_number, row in enumerate(input_list):
        diagonal_point = column_coordinates-row_coordinate+row_number
        if 0 <= diagonal_point <= len(row):
            diagonals[0].append(row[diagonal_point])
        diagonal_point = column_coordinates+row_coordinate-row_number
        if 0 <= diagonal_point <= len(row):
            diagonals[1].append(row[diagonal_point])
    return diagonals
```

Comment: Thank you! The code is working well for (3,2), but it is IndexErroring for (2,3)